# check if two arrays contain identical objects - react componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using React's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

I am trying to determine whether or not two arrays are the same.

My `prevState` array looks like this:

```
prevState.players = [
  {
    name: 'Wayne Rooney',
    age: 31
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lionel Messi',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Robbie Fowler',
    age: 42
  }
];
```

and the `this.state` array looks like this:

```
this.state.players = [
  {
    name: 'Wayne Rooney',
    age: 31
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lionel Messi',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Robbie Fowler',
    age: 42
  }
];
```

As you can see if you expand the snippet below they are not equal:

```js
let playersOne = [{
    name: 'Wayne Rooney',
    age: 31
  },
  {
    name: 'Lionel Messi',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Robbie Fowler',
    age: 42
  }
];

let playersTwo = [{
    name: 'Wayne Rooney',
    age: 31
  },
  {
    name: 'Lionel Messi',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Robbie Fowler',
    age: 42
  }
];

console.log(playersOne == playersTwo)
```

And here is my react lifecycle code.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.players != this.state.players) {
      this.updatePlayers(this.state);
    }
  }
```

can anyone advise as to the best way to determine if the arrays are equal?

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: `JSON.stringify(playersOne) == JSON.stringify(playersTwo)`

Comment: @AkashDathan looks like that one will do it

Comment: One thing that React docs suggest is to use Immutable data since such comparisons can be expensive, but you still need to do it use _.isEqual from lodash or deep compare individual values

Comment: check all the results [**here**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+check+two+arrays+of+objects+are+equal+in+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib6IXV-5DZAhVDvY8KHdswDrkQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1440&bih=803)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(playersOne) == JSON.stringify(playersTwo)`

Comment: HAHAHAHA i love this

Comment: This will backfire if your objects contain cyclic references. the JSON.stringify() method will not work correctly.

Comment: This is also a bad idea if you care about the order of keys in an object....
`JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) !== JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1});`

Comment: @Adzz your example disproves your statement, did you mean "if you don't care about the order of keys" ?

Comment: Whoops, yea typo. If you think the two in the example should be equal, using `JSON.stringify` they would not be.

Comment: This is dangerous territory and will not work for cyclic references (i.e an array of objects with other objects etc.).

Answer (score 5):

1. Using _.isEqual from lodash;
2. Using JSON.stringify and comparing the strings;

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array.prototype.every` :

```js
var players = [
  { name: 'Wayne Rooney'  , age: 31 }, 
  { name: 'Lionel Messi'  , age: 29 },
  { name: 'Robbie Fowler' , age: 42 }
];

var statePlayers = [
  { name: 'Wayne Rooney'  , age: 31 }, 
  { name: 'Lionel Messi'  , age: 29 },
  { name: 'Robbie Fowler' , age: 42 }
];

var equals = players.length === statePlayers.length && players.every((e, i) => e.name === statePlayers[i].name && e.age === statePlayers[i].age);

console.log(equals);
```

Alternatively, using object destructuring and `Array.prototype.some`.

```js
const
  players = [
    { name: 'Wayne Rooney'  , age: 31 }, 
    { name: 'Lionel Messi'  , age: 29 },
    { name: 'Robbie Fowler' , age: 42 }
  ],
  statePlayers = [
    { name: 'Wayne Rooney'  , age: 31 }, 
    { name: 'Lionel Messi'  , age: 29 },
    { name: 'Robbie Fowler' , age: 42 }
  ],
  playersEqual = (expected, actual) =>
    actual.length === expected.length &&
      !expected.some(({ name, age }, i) =>
        (({ name: otherName, age: otherAge }) =>
          name !== otherName || age !== otherAge)
        (actual[i]));

console.log(playersEqual(players, statePlayers));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array#every` to check if both objects have the same number of objects and each object has the same number of key and values.

```js
let playersOne = [{ name: 'Wayne Rooney', age: 31 }, { name: 'Lionel Messi', age: 29 }, { name: 'Robbie Fowler', age: 42 } ],
    playersTwo = [{ name: 'Wayne Rooney', age: 31 }, { name: 'Lionel Messi', age: 29 }, { name: 'Robbie Fowler', age: 42 } ];
 var isSame = playersOne.length === playersTwo.length && playersOne.every((o,i) => Object.keys(o).length === Object.keys(playersTwo[i]).length && Object.keys(o).every(k => o[k] === playersTwo[i][k]));
console.log(isSame);
```

Comment: Good, but I think it would be potentially a bit more efficient to use `.some` and `!==` in the lambda to check if either of the arrays is missing an element of the other.